# Spring Boot dispatcher servlet unable to find/map static contents

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm facing issue while running my SpringMVC app with SpringBoot. The application is able to call the mapped controller and resolve view successfully but is not able to resolve the static contents.

I have read that spring boot automatically sees the following folders for static resource :-
`static`,
`public` 
`Web_INF/resources` etc.,

I have tried keeping my files on following places but still it did not help.

My output on console is :

> Inside Controller 2016-08-23 17:22:12.002 [http-nio-9990-exec-1]
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFoundn] [WARN ]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound: {} - No mapping found
>   for HTTP request with URI [/springBootApp/templates/hello.html] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

where springBootApp is my context root

Below are my classes:-
SpringBoot Class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ServiceApplication.class);
        Set<ApplicationContextInitializer<?>> initLst = app.getInitializers();
        initLst.add(new PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer());
        app.setInitializers(initLst);

        ApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);

        System.out.println("Services Started");
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application = application.initializers(new PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer());

        return application.sources(ServiceApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        //project specific config
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }   

}
```

MVCConfigClass:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ServiceApplication.class, includeFilters = @Filter(Controller.class), useDefaultFilters = false)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolve.setPrefix("/templates/");
        viewResolve.setSuffix(".html");

        return viewResolve;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/templates/**").addResourceLocations("/templates/");
        }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Restful Web Services Class-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/myapp")
public class TestWebService {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/hello" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        // HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        System.out.println("Inside Controller");
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
        ModelMap modelMap = modelView.getModelMap();
        modelView.setViewName("/hello");
        return modelView;
    }

}
```

I get the above output on calling : - http://localhost:9990/springBootApp/myapp/hello

Comment: A `@RestController` is intended to return a response *directly*, such as in JSON or XML. Use a plain `@Controller` if you're wanting to render an HTML template.

Comment: there will be more methods going forward which will return jsons

Comment: @Saumyaraj then you should annotate those with `@ResponseBody` or use separate controllers.

Comment: That's beside the point. Those should be either in a separate controller or in the same controller with `@ResponseBody` applied at the method level instead of the class level.

Comment: modelView.setViewName("/hello"); should be just modelView.setViewName("hello");

Comment: @chrylis Agreed! thanks for suggestion

Comment: @kuhajeyan It is able to resolve the view correctly i.e templates/hello.html as seen from output, but it is handing it over to dispatcher servlet and not resolving it

Answer (score 0):

Extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot automatically find resources in the folder src/main/resources .
but if you implement WebMvcConfigurationSupport methods for resource handling then it remove default implementation of resource handling method.

Comment: Yes, I had overidden the addResource handler but still it was not able to get the static resources